# get flv url from youtube videos

Tags: youtube, flv

for a flash application I am building I need to stream a large flv file. My hosting can't stream this video in a good enough fashion. I decided to host my file on youtube and try and extract the flv file out of it. It is very difficult. This is not a duplicate, there are many questions about this issue. Youtube changed the way they store their flv files. Therefore, all solutions I found up until now don't work.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I have written an article in my blog addressing this issue. Feel free to check it out [here](http://ifthikhan.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/getting-url-for-flv-of-a-youtube-video-in-php/)